# Create a Trigger with merge to monitor tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to create a Trigger to monitor this table :

```
    CREATE TABLE "REFERENCE" 
   (    "NUM_CONTRACT" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),  
    "NATURE" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "PR" VARCHAR2(14 CHAR), 
   )
```

I just want to store the date of the last modification and his "PR" in this table :

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT_REFERENCE (
    ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    reference VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    date_modification TIMESTAMP(6),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

I use a merge in order to avoid to have duplicate rows with the same reference and different date . I just want to keep the date of last modification for each reference rows

For that i created this trigger but idk what's wrong with it . Can anyone help me ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_REFERENCE
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON REFERENCE
                               FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
        MERGE INTO EVENT_REFERENCE hist
        USING (select :new.pr
               from   dual) t1
          ON (t1.pr=hist.reference)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET hist.date_modification=systimestamp
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT INTO EVENT_REFERENCE (REFERENCE, DATE_MODIFICATION)
          VALUES (:NEW.prm, systimestamp);
   END IF;  
   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: "idk what's wrong with it". but you probably got a clue that there is something wrong with it. Do you get an error, unexpected results or what? Why are you making us guess?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can select a bind variable from dual. Also, why use `autonomous_transaction`? This can lead to data corruption, unless your goal is to record the latest *attempted* modification, whether successful or not.

Comment: Oracle did not introduce `IDENITITY` columns until Oracle 12. Are you sure the Oracle 11g tag is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have:

- `:NEW.prm` when it should be `:NEW.pr`
- `INSERT INTO EVENT_REFERENCE (REFERENCE, DATE_MODIFICATION)` when you just need `INSERT (REFERENCE, DATE_MODIFICATION)`

You also use `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` and then check `IF INSERTING` why not just use `AFTER INSERT`?

---

The fixed code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_REFERENCE
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON REFERENCE
                               FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
        MERGE INTO EVENT_REFERENCE hist
        USING DUAL t1
          ON (:new.pr=hist.reference)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET hist.date_modification=systimestamp
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT (REFERENCE, DATE_MODIFICATION)
          VALUES (:NEW.pr, systimestamp);
   END IF;  
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2006443aebd1ca0ebb26a81628ab664f)*